# Webview with photo Kitkat

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

creating an app with a webview in which they appear of photos taken by a web server, on android less than 4.4 pictures fit the screen perfectly while on Android 4.4 kitkat appear zooms, and then a piece of crap. Doing a search I saw that google has changed the webview. I also found this link https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html, but I do not understand what I should change and what for. Does anyone have experience on this topic? can someone give me a hand? thank you!

This is code:

```
    private JSONParser parser;

    private String pkg;
    private ListView listView1;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout01;

    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private int width;

    private Post post;

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

        pkg = getPackageName();
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String page = intent.getStringExtra(pkg + "PAGE");
        String title = intent.getStringExtra(pkg + "TITLE");

        setTitle(title);

        parser = new JSONParser();

        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        linearLayout01 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout01);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width = display.getWidth();

        webView = new WebView(this);

        new LoadSchermataTremore(page).execute();
    }

private class LoadSchermataTremore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Post>>{

        private Post post;
        private String mPage;
        private List<Post> lstPost = new ArrayList<Post>();

        public LoadSchermataTremore (String page){
            this.mPage = page;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Post> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {


                post = new Post();

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://url.it/?json=get_page&id=" + mPage); //URL address
                Log.v(TAG, "page: http://url.it/?json=get_page&id=" + mPage);
                HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();

                String result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

//              Log.v(TAG, "post: " + result);

                post = parser.postFromJson(result);

//              String htmlText = " %s ";
//              
//              WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
//              webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
//              webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, post.getContent()), "text/html", null);
//              
//              linearLayout01.addView(webView);

                HTMLParser htmlParser = new HTMLParser();
                lstPost = htmlParser.postsFromHtml(post.getContent());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "LoadSchermataTremore(),Exception: " + e);
            }

             return lstPost;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Post> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {

            Log.v(TAG, "post: " + post.getContent());

            String htmlText = " %s ";


            webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
            webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, post.getContent()), "text/html", null);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
//              @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "url: " + url);
                    Intent share = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShareActivity.class);
                    share.putExtra(pkg + "LINK", url);

                    startActivity(share);
                    return true;
                  }
            });

            linearLayout01.addView(webView);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LoadSchermataTremore(),Exception: " + e);
        }


//          WebAdapter webAdapter = new WebAdapter(LiveActivity.this);
//          
//          for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
//              webAdapter.add(result.get(i));
//          }
//          
//          listView1.setAdapter(webAdapter);
//          
            try {
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    dialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

private class WebAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post>{
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public WebAdapter(LiveActivity activity) {
        super(activity, 0);
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_web, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvTitolo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRowWeb);
            holder.wvPost = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wvImgWeb);
            holder.ivWeb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivWeb);
            holder.tvlink = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLink);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Post post = getItem(position);

        holder.tvTitolo.setText(post.getTitle());


        holder.wvPost.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

        holder.wvPost.loadUrl(post.getThumbnail());

        holder.wvPost.setFocusable(false);
        holder.wvPost.setClickable(false);

        holder.tvlink.setText(post.getUrl());

        return convertView;
    }
}

private String generateHTLM(String title,String image){
    String str = "";
    str = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='http:urlcouraselcss.css' />" +
          "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js'></script>" +
          "<script src='http://url'></script>" +
          "<script type='text/javascript'>" +

          "</div>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<br>" +
          "<br>" +
          "<br>" +
          "</body>";

    return str;
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    TextView tvTitolo;
    TextView tvlink;
    ImageView ivWeb;
    TextView tvContent;
    WebView wvPost;
    TextView tvIDPost;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML and how you have set up the WebView in Java?

Comment: webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
   webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
   webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, post.getContent()), "text/html", null);
   
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

Comment: OK, I think the difference in rendering is explained by `webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);` which is not supported in KitKat. If you remove that line, does the content look the same on KK and older versions? It may not be how you want it to look, we'll fix that next. But consistency is important :)

Comment: This line of code is commented

Comment: not in the snippet you posted in onPostExecute. Did removing it make any difference?

Comment: nada de nada...help meee